# Linq get element from string list and a position of a char in this list

Tags: list, linq, substring, contains

i want to get an element from a list of string and get the position of a char in this list by using linq ?

Example :

```
List<string> lines = new List<string> { "TOTO=1", "TATA=2", "TUTU=3"}
```

I want to extract the value 1 from TOTO in the list

here is the begin of my code

```
var value= lines.ToList().Single(x =>x.Contains("TOTO=")).ToString().Trim();
```

How to continue this code to extract 1 ?

Comment: Why you want 1 as a result? That's what position of a char in this list? You want instead two results, the string `"1"` and the index `5`?

Answer (score 1):

Add this :

```
value = value[(value.LastIndexOf('=') + 1)..];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ you can do this:

```cs
List<string> lines = new List<string> { "TOTO=1", "TATA=2", "TUTU=3" };

int value = lines
    .Select(line => line.Split('='))
    .Where(parts => parts[0] == "TOTO")
    .Select(parts => int.Parse(parts[1]))
    .Single();
```

If you always expect each item in that list to be in the proper format then this should work, otherwise you'd need to add some validation.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to What @jtate proposed, Some minor enhancements can help.

```
int value = lines
    .Select(line => line.Split(new []{ '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Where(parts => string.Equals(parts[0], "TOTO", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .Select(parts => int.Parse(parts[1]))
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

**SingleOrDefault** - If you don't find any elements matching your constraints, Single() would thow an exception. Here, SingleOrDefault would return 0;

**String.Equals** - would take care of any upper lowere or any culture related problems.

**StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries** - would limit some unecessary iterations and improve performance.

Also see if you need int.TryParse instead of int.Prase. All these checks would help cover edges cases in production